# Drawing a diagram to illustrate this cnn+lstm network

Tags: keras

I am drawing a diagram to represent the following network (programmed using keras) I used for sentence classification:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer) # this layer represents each sentence as a length of 50 words, each having 300 dimensions
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=4, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the diagram I have created. Is it correct? [image: diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty correct to me in terms of shapes:

- **Embedding:** a matrix with 50 words, 300 features. Shape `(None,50,300)`
- **Convolution:** keeps the 50 words (padding='same'), creates 100 channes (one for each of the 100 filters). Shape `(None, 50, 100)`
- **MaxPooling(4):** divides 50/4 in length, remaining 12 (rounded, but check the model summary for 12 or 13). Keeps the 100 channels. Shape `(None,12,100)`
- **LSTM(100):** considers 12 steps and 100 features, outputting 12 steps (return_sequences=True) and keeping 100 features (units=100). Shape `(None,12,100)`
- **GlobalMaxPooling:** = removes the length, keeps only 100 features. Shape `(None,100)`
- **Dense(n):**, leaves only n features at the end. Shape `(None,n)`

You can check all the output shapes in `model.summary()`.

**The red and blue rectangles:**

About the red and blue rectangles describing the convolutions, each pass will generate 100 channels from the 300 input channels. So the red and blue targets cover the entire 100 output channels.

Also, since the blue rectangle is two steps to the right of the red, its outputs will also be two steps to the right. Convolutions walk 1 by 1 in length, unless you set `stride` to a bigger number. I added yet another rectangle below to make sure that the stride is understood as 1.

[image]

**The shaded rectangles:**

I know these two are not connected by lines, but it might make people think that the shaded rectangles before the LSTM relate to the ones after the LSTM.

So maybe change their colors?

[image]

**The layer identifications to the right of the picture:**

I think you could move the `1D Convolution` label that is at the right of the diagram a little upwards, because I'm confusing it with the embedding.

[image]

Comment: thank you this is great details. Re 'the red and blue rectangles' the stride is 1 indeed, so the red and blue boxes should have a gap of 1 column so it's not misleading, right? Also, is 'input channel' the same as 'filter'? In principle i understand that basically the 300 becomes 100 due to this 'filter' setting but in practice I am not sure what exactly happens to reduce this.

Comment: Ideally, you should move the blue rectangles one pixel to the left. The movement happens one by one. In the current image, the blue box is 2 steps from red.

Comment: Input channel is not the same as filter (I corrected my texts a little). But the number of output channels in a convolutional layer is equal to the number of filters it has. Each filter will gather all the input channels and create one output channel.